# How to enable install from url in Drupal Commons?

Tags: 7

I cannot find any option to install the modules from a url.
Currently, I am installing them through cpanel by manually uploading, unzipping etc.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Make sure you have the Update module enabled...

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush)

> Drush or drupal shell is a command-line utility to help the site
>   building and maintenance workflows.

The following will download and enable the module:

```
drush en module_name -y
```

Example Commands

```
drush dl cck zen
```

Download current recommended versions of CCK module and Zen theme.

```
drush en content
```

Enable the content (cck) module.

```
 drush vset theme_default theme_name
```

make theme_name theme default theme